# Background colour of table row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple table where I change the row colour using jQuery when the user hover the row elements.

```
$('tr').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).css({background:'#f00'});
});
$('tr').on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).css({background:''});
});
```

When the user moves the mouse from column A to column B (on the same row), the `mouseout` event is fired.

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/8sy3L4jk/).

Test case: Move mouse over cell with 'Foo' in it. Move mouse right, to cell with 'Bar' in it. The row should remain red, but does not.

Tested in IE11 and Chrome 42.0.2311.152m. CSS isn't appropriate due to the selector I'm actually using. (Attached ia a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The mouseout event triggers when the mouse pointer leaves any child
>   elements as well the selected element.
>
> The mouseleave event is only triggered when the mouse pointer leaves
>   the selected element.

Use `mouseleave` event instead of `mouseout`:

```
$('tr').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).css({background:'#f00'});
});
$('tr').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).css({background:''});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just use CSS for dealing with styling:

```
tr:hover {
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8sy3L4jk/2/)

Comment: CSS isn't appropriate - I'm using a more complex selector in reality. Edit made, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Better you can use **[hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)**

```
$('tr').hover(function () {
    $(this).css({background:'#f00' });
}, function () {
     $(this).css({background:'' });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8sy3L4jk/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:
Apply the `mouseenter`/`mouseout` events to the `td`, and then use `$(this).parent().css({background:...});` instead.

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/8sy3L4jk/1/).